# running ant application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am able to build the ant file in eclipse.
How to run the ant application through eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To run an Ant script from within Eclipse, add the xml file to your
workspace.  If you open its context menu, you should see a choice "Run
Ant...".

via: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg18883.html

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing that:

1. There is a main class where you have defined a `public static void main(String... args)` method. So just run this class (right-click on the class, "Run as > Java Application".
2. Define an Ant `target` that will run your main Java class, and then run this target through Ant Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly drag and drop Ant files onto the Ant View (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, type 'ant'). From there, I run the default target by double-clicking the file in the view, or other targets by expanding the file in the view.